# Algorithm to store Item-to-Item-Associations

Tags: java, algorithm, memory, associations

I need some help to store some data efficiently. I have a large list of objects (about 100.000) and want to store associations between this items with a coefficient. Not all items are associated, in fact I have something about 1 Mio. Associations. I need fast access to these associations when referencing by the two items. What I did is a structure like that:

```
Map<Item, Map<Item, Float>>
```

I tried this with `HashMap` and `Hashtable`. Both work fine and is fast enough. My problem is, that all that Maps create a lot of overhead in memory, concrete for the given scenario more than 300 MB. Is there a Map-Implementation with less footprint? Is there maybe a better algorithm to store that kind of data?

Comment: Are you doing any sorting as well?

Comment: Anything more memory efficient will probably have to exploit some particularity of your Items. Also, is this supposed to be something that is updated a lot?

Comment: No sorting while storing. In fact my "Float" is a complexe Object, which can be sorted in more than one way, so sorting is a following step. Data is update very often

Comment: Could you give us a better description on `Float` ? would it be possible to have in all that list two `Float` objects that are basically identical ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some ideas:

1. Store in a `Map<Pair<Item,Item>,Float>`. If you are worried about allocating a new `Pair` for each lookup, and your code is synchronized, you can keep a single lookup Pair instance.
2. Loosen the outer map to be `Map<Item, ?>`. The value can be a simple `{Item,Float}` tuple for the first association, a small tuple array for a small number of associations, then promote to a full fledged Map.
3. Use Commons Collections' [`Flat3Map`](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections/map/Flat3Map.html) for the inner maps.
4. If you are in tight control of the Items, and Item equivalence is referential (i.e. each Item instance is not `equal` to any other Item instance, then you can number each instance. Since you are talking about < 2 billion instances, a single Long will represent an Item pair with some bit manipulation. Then the map gets much smaller if you use Trove's [`TLongObjectHashMap`](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/javadocs/gnu/trove/TLongObjectHashMap.html)

Comment: Thanks for your ideas, thats what I'm looking for. Will get a long night tonight ;)

Comment: You solved my problem indirectly. While implementiung your idea 4, I found out, that I created a new instance of that Item-Object for each Key. Thats where my memory went to. Inner and outer maps are OK.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options.

1) Reduce what you're storing.

If your data is calculable, using a WeakHashMap will allow the garbage collector to remove members.  You will probably want to decorate it with a mechanism that calculates lost or absent key/value pairs on the fly.  This is basically a cache.

Another possibility that might trim a relatively tiny amount of RAM is to instruct your JVM to use compressed object pointers.  That may save you about 3 MB with your current data size.

2) Expand your capacity.

I'm not sure what your constraint is (run-time memory on a desktop, serialization, etc.) but you can either expand the heapsize and deal with it, or you can push it out of process.  With all those "NoSQL" stores out there, one will probably fit your needs.  Or, an indexed db table can be quite fast.  If you're looking for a simple key-value store, Voldemort is extremely easy to set up and integrate.

However, I don't know what you're doing with your working set.  Can you give more details?  Are you performing aggregations, partitioning, cluster analysis, etc.?  Where are you running into trouble?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My dataset is going to grow, so I need a resource-efficient solution, Memoy is expensive in the cloud. Moving to a noSQl DB is a step for the future, that I want to stall as long as possible. Even after that step, I will need a appropriate data-structure for caching

Comment: Are your keys and values typed in any particular way?